# ECDSA public key generated with constant prefix?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have some javascript, which generates new ECDSA public-private keypair.
However all the resulting public keys which I generate seem to have fixed prefix.

This seems strange to me, since the beginning is always the same. Is this correct? Or should I expect all pub keys to be more random?

Here is example of generated public keys (base58 encoded):

```
aSq9DsNNvGhYxYyqA9wd2eduEAZ5AXWgJTbTG9WCdoLJo5PbBdaXeKUGoXBiZWLoFszaWcRnyUmgo3jdUkAtnoJijjUooeKUvRcqp5y3w4cXN85dPhTFrGpYmXMG
aSq9DsNNvGhYxYyqA9wd2eduEAZ5AXWgJTbTHWqMbneiD8TN5wntMvV8MgbZviYT3aiBCVUqmdxhNj7tFqRtJ6kdHB9qZsFv7py6Gn1cYQKSJouZKA2hayDrenrQ
aSq9DsNNvGhYxYyqA9wd2eduEAZ5AXWgJTbTHMgQX5y6PNueefoCSiMP45C9nocEKsqHqoeXDkJYvdHUCS7zwSCjpw8E4ggBEp7z1jMTtLmy2PJRqgGGAuzskX7U
aSq9DsNNvGhYxYyqA9wd2eduEAZ5AXWgJTbTJQ7HgMHUSamB9RmgnKBHQv6axkUwfvFc1PiHKq1SimHrh9CXPt8V3LwW3W5up6nettkhHkoQPCWTZYadPnkmgv8L
aSq9DsNNvGhYxYyqA9wd2eduEAZ5AXWgJTbTJuVVHkx37iQeM9FYXymYkeuFEDGkytjQrkTkdCxkQtWzMt1qYPki77jcPbsQdYehDtirMMR8V1CSzLgynr8B4vaz
aSq9DsNNvGhYxYyqA9wd2eduEAZ5AXWgJTbTGWhozoV5vzA5UbNKriS4uyV43S3oxGB1B5rHJKHN4LvtX1aSsQX7jL7dio5BdmDR68N2YZFLomnLyn82gETxFdUf
```

Comment: My guess would be that the prefix is some ASN.1 structuring that also indicates the used curve and byte lengths.

Comment: You will need to specify what library you're talking about.  Otherwise, who knows what metadata it adds to its public key format?

Comment: I thought that a binary representation of the public key is given, platform-independant, library-independant. It is not?

Comment: There is one fairly commonly used standard, X.509's SubjectPublicKeyInfo more conveniently described in rfc 3279 et rel, and that is what you have, but there are quite a few other formats used by some program(s) or library(ies).

Comment: I'm sure this is just a encoding problem and is not "cryptographically" on-topic here. How can I flag it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keys are ASN.1 structures. I decoded first one to hex:

```
3059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D03010703420004405134B8399A666F12ADA32F19F646F85FB7D1FC3D9AA0688BF8984A35B86AD49FBB96CFAD78B994013D06D7B98C09B0104323DD0A2473CDCA79342277027D3F
```

When I gave this to ASN.1 parser, it shows me the next structure:

```
SEQUENCE
----SEQUENCE
--------ObjectIdentifier 1.2.840.10045.2.1 [ecPublicKey]
--------ObjectIdentifier 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 [prime256v1]
----BITSTRING [04405134b8399a666f12ada32f19f646f85fb7d1fc3d9aa0688bf8984a35b86ad49fbb96cfad78b994013d06d7b98c09b0104323dd0a2473cdca79342277027d3f]
```

So, your keys have the same prefix, because they contain algorithm identifier and curve identifier. Public key is just EC point.

Comment: So, basically, if the software (javascript native crypto) generates the keys I have, is it safe to use them? Does it bring any security risk to publish the keys while they contain the identifiers?

Comment: No risks, secp256r1 is the most widely used curve. Even without these identifiers it is easy to guess them.